# Applying custom mixin and lookups with Q objects behavior

Tags: django, django-queryset, mixins

I have the following mixin in which I want retrieve the User model data to place these data on different clase based views that I am developing:

```
class UserProfileDataMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileDataMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        #context['userprofile'] = user.profile
        if user.is_authenticated():
            context['userprofile'] = user.profile
        return context
```

Then, I have the following search view in which I have lookup users according to the following criteria with Q objects:

When we search by `username` and `full_name` field

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        context = {"users": qs}

        return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

When I inherit from `UserProfileDataMixin` this mixin gives me the possibility of having the `userprofile` context variable to pass it to my `search.html` template, which inherit from `layout.html` template, in which I perform the following validation:

**search.html template**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
```

**layout.html template**

```
{% if userprofile %}
    I put the data of user by example:
    avatar, username, full_name, and menu options to my app.   
{% endif %}
```

Until here, alls OK, but my class based view `SearchView` does not apply the `UserProfileDataMixin` because, I cannot get the user data on my template, which coming from `layout.html`.

When I get the search users template I get that:

[image]

I've change slightly my class based view `SearchView` overriding the `get_queryset` method instead of `get` method a

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
        template_name = 'search.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        context = {"users": qs}
        return render(self.request, "search.html", context)
```

And my my class based view `SearchView` apply the `UserProfileDataMixin` because I can get the user data from `layout.html` on my template. Now appear my top header menu which is bring by  `UserProfileDataMixin`

[image]

But I have now the inconvenient of my Q lookup query does not works

Why is the reason to `UserProfileDataMixin` does not applied on my class based view `SearchView` when I override the `get` method but if when I override `get_queryset` method, but this remove the effect of my custom lookup q object query?

When should I use `get`,and when use `get_queryset`?

In [this answer question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950584/2773461) explain about of the subject, and I think that use the `get_queryset` is suited, but, why my query is not performed of the same way as when I use `get` method? And why using the get method my `UserProfileDataMixin` is not inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base implementation of `get()` calls `get_context_data()` for you. However, because you have overridden `get()` with your own implementation, you would need to call `get_context_data()` yourself.

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )

        # Get the context data from the base class (mixin) and update it
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data()
        context["users"] = qs

        return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

However, a better solution may be to not override `get()` at all, and implement a view specific `get_context_data()` in your `SearchView`. e.g.

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["users"] = qs
        return context
```

Lastly, your `get_queryset()` implementation is not doing the right thing, because that method is meant to return a QuerySet object, whereas in your case it is rendering a template.