# Django CBV : get() and get_context_data()

Tags: django

I would like to get some indicators about `get()` and `get_context_data()` classes because I get an issue and I'm trying to understand why.

I have a `Django DetailView` which let to display some statistics with multiple querysets. In the same class, I have a `query string` which shows the result from a get queryset.

My code looks like this :

```
class StatsView(DetailView):
    """ Create statistics pageview """
    template_name = 'app/stats.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def set_if_not_none(self, mapping, key, value):
        if value is not None:
            if len(value) != 0:
                mapping[key] = value

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return context_data
```

Like this, `get_context_data()` function doesn't work, but when I set `get()` in comment, it works fine. I think there is a small misunderstanding from myself.

Maybe I don't use the good django generic display view or maybe it's not possible to use `get()` and `get_context_data()` together in the same class ?

Thank you

I read the Django documentation but I would like to get explanations from you

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to pass querysets from `get()` method to `get_context_data()`. Then I removed `get()` method, I changed `DetailView` by `TemplateView` and it works with just `get_context_data()`. But how I can add a "skeleton" without `get()` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass querysets from get() method to get_context_data()

```
class StatsView(DetailView):
    """ Create statistics pageview """
    template_name = 'app/stats.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=self.get_context_data(queryset=queryset))

    def set_if_not_none(self, mapping, key, value):
        if value is not None:
            if len(value) != 0:
                mapping[key] = value

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.get('queryset')
        # do something
```

If your overriding **`get_context_data()`** method, it's advaisable to call the `super()` method as

```
class StatsView(DetailView):
    # your code

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data.update({"foo": "bar"})
        return data
```

---

> I would like to get some indicators about **`get()`** and **`get_context_data()`**

I think it's nicely answered here already , [When to use get, get_queryset, get_context_data in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950416/when-to-use-get-get-queryset-get-context-data-in-django)