# How do I add context/an additional dictionary to Django DayArchiveView

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a DayArchiveView where I pass in a queryset of booking slots. I would like to be able to pass in some context too, like more data. Specifically, I would like to pass the earliest time, latest time and a few other small calculations.

My view is currently this.

```
class BookingArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
     queryset = BookingSlot.objects.filter(location__club__id=1)
     date_field = "start_time"
     ordering = ['location']
     #I would like to pass in another object like so
     context["earliest_time"]=BookingSlot.objects.filter(location__club__id=1).annotate(Min('start_time'))
```

So I would like to be able to pass in some aggregate functions and calculations that I could render in html. Right now, the HTML only has access to my queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override `get_context_data()` method? In this method you should add any extra data you want to pass to html template.
Another way is to update your context in `get()` method, but in this case the first solution will be better.

More details you can find here [When to use get, get_queryset, get_context_data in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950416/when-to-use-get-get-queryset-get-context-data-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `get_context_data()` to your CBV

Example below

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['calculation'] = some_random_number
    return context
```

Then you can access variables you declared in your `get_context_data()` in your html's like `{{ calculation }}`